# How Can I Use Functions in PHP Pages with Forms?

Tags: php, html, forms, function, inputbox

I have a html form on my php webpage. There are four input box. And I'm adding new data with these.

I want to do that, when I write something in input box1, input box2 will be same but with "-" instead of a space..

For example when I write "how are you" to input box1, input box2 must be "how-are-you".. How can I do that? :/

Comment: As an aside (since I don't really have time right now to do a full answer), this functionality would be best done client-side, using JavaScript.

Comment: Use Ajax for doing this thing.

Comment: AJAX would be overkill if this is all you need it for.  No sense in using a whole Javascript library for just a few simple lines of basic Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

just add this JavaScript on your page

```
   document.getElementById('box1').onkeyup = function (){
    document.getElementById('box2').value = document.getElementById('box1').value.replace(' ','-')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple bit of jQuery.  When the text in the first box changes, set the text in the second box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript in order to do this without a page reload.  PHP only operates on the server.

Comment: True and false... you could achieve it with AJAX and PHP, though that does involve Javascript (but can also utilize the server-side php).